# Running Same Minecraft Server On Two Machines At Once

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

Is it possible to make two computers run a single minecraft server? I know there are clusters out there but I don't know if that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for Serverfault - It's about the operations of servers... And should be reworded for Serverfault SE.

Comment: @aytimothy I very much doubt this could be made acceptable for serverfault.

Comment: You're sure right... @TZHX - Aren't they more about data processing/administration? (That close reason was based on a quick glanze at their 'tour' and 'FAQ')

Comment: Please don't spam your question on 3 different Stack Exchange questions, especially when the question is off-topic for all three sites.

Comment: @EatMyTacoCrumbs I think he originally posted it on Stack Overflow, then they asked him to go to Gamedev, and finally - Gamedev asked him to go here... And now we're asking him to go to Serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

A [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) cluster *might* achieve the desired effect (I'm not an expert), but the technicalities of how to set this up are too extensive to cover in this question! Clusters are complex, and I wouldn't advise trying to use one unless you're an accomplished server administrator.

**You almost certainly don't want to use a cluster anyway.** The main benefit of cluster computing is parallelisation; the effect is similar to having a CPU with more cores. Minecraft is almost entirely single-threaded though, meaning that extra processor cores won't really improve performance much; **instead, you should aim to use *faster, single-threaded processors* (over 3GHz), not more (or multi-core) processors.**

Answer (score 1):

**No**, this is not possible.
Due to the way Minecraft, Bukkit and Spigot are coded, you cannot run the same instance of a server on two machines.
Minecraft worlds are locked to one instance at a time, and that instances of the software cannot share data (plus it's inefficient anyway).

The only way to do this is that you have turn off one before using another on the same set of data.

---

You're better off using Bungiecord to redirect one machine to the other.

[image: Setup comparisons]

Basically, servers can use the same database, but **cannot** use the same world.

Comment: You didn't answer my question at all. I want to use cluster computing to power one minecraft server.

Comment: @Maihym Wait.. Clusters as in two (or more) machines to form more-or-less one virtural machine, like how Google's running on servers world-wide?